# How to implement a specific comparator without using the lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda, parameter-passing, overriding

I get the following code from [here](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/50481/clean-16ms-c-o-n-space-o-klogn-time-solution-using-priority-queue).

```
class Solution {
public:
  vector<pair<int, int>> kSmallestPairs(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2, int k) {
    vector<pair<int,int>> result;
    if (nums1.empty() || nums2.empty() || k <= 0)
        return result;
    auto comp = [&nums1, &nums2](pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {
        return nums1[a.first] + nums2[a.second] > nums1[b.first] + nums2[b.second];};
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(comp)> min_heap(comp);
    min_heap.emplace(0, 0);
    while(k-- > 0 && min_heap.size())
    {
        auto idx_pair = min_heap.top(); min_heap.pop();
        result.emplace_back(nums1[idx_pair.first], nums2[idx_pair.second]);
        if (idx_pair.first + 1 < nums1.size())
            min_heap.emplace(idx_pair.first + 1, idx_pair.second);
        if (idx_pair.first == 0 && idx_pair.second + 1 < nums2.size())
            min_heap.emplace(idx_pair.first, idx_pair.second + 1);
    }
    return result;
  }
};
```

There is one line of the lambda expression to implement the comparator:

```
auto comp = [&nums1, &nums2](pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {
        return nums1[a.first] + nums2[a.second] > nums1[b.first] + nums2[b.second];};
```

`pair.first` indexes the first array `nums1` while `pair.second` indexes the second array `nums2`.

This comparator compares two pairs, where each pair contains the indices of two arrays(vector). The expression returns true if the first pair (array1[first_pair.first]+array2[first_pair.second]) has the corresponding array sum greater than the second pair.

My **QUESTION** is, can we use a struct to implement the same comparator? The difficult part is how to we pass the two arrays as the arguments to the comparator.

A struct that compare two pair (not the index of two arrays) can be implemented in this way:

```
struct myCompare {
  bool operator() (const pair<int,int> lhs, const pair<int,int> rhs) const
  { return (lhs.first+lhs.second < rhs.first+rhs.second); }
};
```

But this is to compare the sum of the pair entries. Now we want to compare the sum of two array entries indexed by the pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the arrays in the comparator's constructor.

```
struct myCompare {

  // pass capture variables using constructor
  myCompare(const std::vector<int>& nums1, std::vector<int>& nums2)
  : nums1(nums1), nums2(nums2) {}

  bool operator() (const pair<int,int> lhs, const pair<int,int> rhs) const
  { return (nums1[lhs.first] + nums2[lhs.second] < nums1[rhs.first] + nums2[rhs.second]); }

private:
  const std::vector<int>& nums1;
  const std::vector<int>& nums2;
};
```

Then use it like:

```
myCompare comp(nums1, nums2);

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, myCompare> min_heap(comp);
```

Comment: This solution is nice. It inspires me that we can also use two iterators pointing to `array.begin()` as the member variables of the comparator. And the entry can be accessed by `begin_iterator+index`.

Answer (score 0):

Use comparator with constructor. See below. Note, we pass constructor and operator parameters by const reference.

```
struct MyCompare
{
    MyCompare(const vector<int>& arOne, const vector<int>& arTwo)
        : nums1(arOne), nums2(arTwo)
    {}

    bool operator() (const pair<int,int>& lhs, const pair<int,int>& rhs) const
    {
        return nums1[lhs.first] + nums2[lhs.second] 
               > nums1[rhs.first] + nums2[rhs.second];
    }

    const vector<int>& nums1;
    const vector<int>& nums2;
};
```

// Define as follows

```
std::priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int> >, MyCompare> 
min_heap(MyCompare(arOne, arTwo));
```